# Does iptables work in kernel mode?

Tags: linux, permissions, iptables

I am not sure about that. It *should* run in kernel mode in order to avoid some user-mode program to kill/suspend the firewall and do its dirty job.
The malware would not be able to kill the firewall even if it was able to get higher privileges.
Hope in deep explaination for both Windows (consider a generic firewall) and Linux machines.
Thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`iptables` is a user-mode program that acts as an interface to the [Netfilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter) hooks that the Linux kernel provides. By it's very definition, it cannot run in kernel mode as it is a user-mode program designed to *interface* with a set of kernel hooks.

`iptables` can only be modified by the `root` user anyway. If a piece of malware manages to elevate privileges that high, you are screwed anyway. It's *impossible* (or at least close to impossible) to defend against a malicious root user.

Comment: True. We've also to consider though, that if you run an untrusted and unknown application as root, then you are going to expect/deserve anything.

Answer (score 1):

Terry's answer is correct, protecting against a malicious root user is just not possible.

Some further information:

iptables is the userspace command line program used to configure the Linux and later packet filtering ruleset (used to interface onto netfilter which is the kernel side of the firewall). Netfilter is a set of hooks inside the Linux kernel that allows kernel modules to register callback functions with the network stack. A registered callback function is then called back for every packet that traverses the respective hook within the network stack.

On windows this is the WFP (Windows Filtering Platform). Windows Filtering Platform (WFP) is a set of API and system services that provide a platform for creating network filtering applications. The WFP API allows developers to write code that interacts with the packet processing that takes place at several layers in the networking stack of the operating system. Network data can be filtered and also modified before it reaches its destination. The WFP API consists of a user-mode API and a kernel-mode API. This section provides an overview of the entire WFP and describes in detail only the user-mode portion of the WFP API.

Comment: It is possible to protect against a malicious root user using MAC (SELinux, Grsecurity) or dropping capabilities. However, the MAC policy has to be configured for your use case.